# Discord Bot, Sending A Message Every 24 Hours

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like to ask anyone who knows Python. I plan to make my discord bot send a certain message at a certain time. I was planning on making it remind me and other people for a certain occasion. On my end, I would like the bot to send that message every 24 hours. My code works when looping the message however, it only works when I use minutes or seconds. If I try to input days or hours, it won't work. I also tried to input the number of minutes/seconds for 24 hours and it wouldn't work as well. Below this text would be my code. Does anyone here know how to solve this, or at least find an alternate solution? I'm quite unsure of how to work with tasks and loops. I give you my thanks in advance.

```
@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def e():
    await client.get_channel(channel id here).send("@everyone It's A New Day!")


@e.before_loop
async def before_e():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

e.start()
```

Comment: You are better off running it on a AWS EC2 instance as a CRON job.

Comment: Did you start the loop at all?

Comment: @yudhiesh I see. Thank you for the answer. I was having a hard time figuring what to do.

Comment: @12944qwerty Yes I did. I did some test runs and it works perfectly for seconds and minutes. It, unfortunately, does not work when I used hours.

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? As long as you start the loop it should work

Comment: @12944qwerty I apologize for being unclear. If I input hours=24, the message will be sent 24 minutes later than when I started the loop and not 24 hours.

Comment: try printing the time before and after the `wait_until_ready`

Comment: @Ceres will do. Thank you.

Comment: @Ceres Excuse me for being a bit annoying but what did you mean by printing the time?

Comment: `print(datetime.now())`, to check when the bot is ready and if that's what is causing your error.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `Advanced Python Scheduler` for doing it in a better way.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger

async def sendNewDayMessage():
    await client.get_channel(channel_id).send("@everyone It's A New Day!")

sched = AsyncIOScheduler()
sched.start()
sched.add_job(sendNewDayMessage, CronTrigger(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)) #on 00:00
```